# Pass Excel version as parameter to Cognos

Tags: java, cognos-8

We form the URL in our java application and pass it to the cognos server to generate reports. At the moment the Excel reports are defaulting to 2002. Is there a way to pass the Excel version number, to change it to 2007, to the cognos server via the URL?

I know this can be done in the Cognos server for each report by manually setting the excel version but want to know if there is parameter value that we can pass via the URL to set the excel version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have found the solution. Use `run.outputFormat=spreadsheetML` to tell Cognos to generate excel spreadsheets in Excel 2007 format.

Formats supported by Cognos are `CSV, HTML, HTMLFragment, MHT, PDF, singleXLS, XHTML, layoutDataXML, spreadsheetML, rawXML, XLWA, and XML`

Source: [Using parametrized URLs to perform tasks](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v35r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.tivoli.tcr.doc_31%2Fttcr_urls.html)